# Select row with maximum matched records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, best-first-search

I am facing trouble to get the desired result from MySQL query. I have a table named 'lyricist' and the columns are 'keywords' and 'name'.

```
SELECT name FROM `lyricist` WHERE keywords LIKE '%আমরা%' or keywords LIKE '%সোনার%' or keywords LIKE '%সয়না%'
```

But it gives two rows because আমরা and সোনার these two words are from row1 and সয়না is from row2. But I want to get the one row that matches the maximum words from like words. And if two rows have same number of match words than it may return the first one.

```
SELECT name, count(*) FROM `lyricist` WHERE keywords LIKE '%আমরা%' or keywords LIKE '%আয়%'
```

This returns one row but count result isn't exact! How can I do that? I tried with max, regex, match but didn't get correct result !

Comment: You should normalize your keywords (Separate table) to correct operations with it.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with @vp_arth, keywords belong in their own table.

```
+----------+-------------+
| keyword  | lyricist_id |
+----------+-------------+
```

then you could do this

```
SELECT count(*) AS c FROM keyword where FIND_IN_SET(keyword, 'আমরা,সোনার') GROUP BY lyricist_id ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT 1;
```

If that's not possible, you could do something like this.

```
SELECT `name`, IF(FIND_IN_SET('আমরা', `keywords`), 1, 0) + IF(FIND_IN_SET('সোনার', `keywords`), 1, 0) as `matches` FROM `lyricist` ORDER BY `matches` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

This uses a series of `IF` statements that return 1 or 0 depending on whether a match is found. The results are summed into `matches`.
This does work, but will be more difficult to maintain, and less efficient.

Note the use of mysql's `FIND_IN_SET` function (instead of just using `LIKE`) This will prevent issues arising from partial matches on the keyword list - for example, with `LIKE`, a search on 'happy' would match both 'happy' and 'unhappy' in the keyword list.

Comment: I have tried the following query and it works ! :D "select name, max(num) from (SELECT name, count()as num FROM lyric_test.l2 WHERE keywords LIKE 'আমরা' or keywords LIKE 'আয়' or keywords LIKE 'যা' UNION ALL SELECT name, count()as num FROM lyric_test.l1 WHERE keywords LIKE 'আমরা' or keywords LIKE 'আয়' or keywords LIKE 'যা')as t GROUP BY name ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 1"

Answer (score 1):

Like others said generally is is best practise to normalize your data and keep keywords in different table.But in case for some reason you want to keep them a comma separated string a solution would be fetch all the matching records like you do now and then find the one you want using php.Something like this would work:

```
$val="keyword1,keyword2,keyword3";
$keywords=explode(',',$val);

// CODE TO CONSTRUCT YOUR QUERY HERE
//

$result=mysqli($query);
if(mysqli_num_rows>0){
     $max_matches=0;
     while ($lyricist = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $lyricist_keywords=explode($lyricist->keywords);    
        $matches=count(array_intersect($keywords, $lyricist_keywords));
        if($matches>$max_matches) $best_match=$lyricist;
    }

    var_dump($best_match);
}
```